# Best sealer/finisher for wooden coaster?

Tags: wood

We are making wooden coasters and at present are using a water based polyurethane. My question is there a better solution/product that would result in a better finish/seal?

Comment: water poly will dissolve from...water. I personally would use a food-safe oil like walnut or even canola. If you needed them extra durable, a spray acrylic (aka clear spray paint, aka clear coat) would be tough and permanent.

Comment: I would suggest this be migrated to [woodworking.se] where there is an entire tag or two dedicated to wood finishing, as well as a tremendous amount of expertise on the topic. Actually, I'd suggest searching the [finishing tag](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing) there first to see if you can find an answer to your question without even having to ask it.